# How can I test an action after a promise throws an exception?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm writing some tests with Vue and Jest, I need to test if a toast is open with an error message after a service throws an exception. I wrote the same test for the success case, but I can't achieve the oposite result.

**success case**

```js
    it('shows a success toast after delete', async () => {
      jest.spyOn(fontService, 'deleteUser').mockResolvedValueOnce(true);
      const wrapper = await createWrapper(); // custom function
      wrapper.vm.$toast.open = jest.fn();
      wrapper.vm.deleteUser('my_user_id');
      await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

      expect(wrapper.vm.$st.toast.open).toBeCalledWith({
        type: 'success',
        content: 'User was successfully deleted',
      });
    });
```

**error case (not working)**

```js
    it('shows an error toast trying to delete', async () => {
      jest.spyOn(fontService, 'deleteUser').mockImplementation(() => { throw new Error('error') });
      const wrapper = await createWrapper(); // custom function
      wrapper.vm.$toast.open = jest.fn();
      wrapper.vm.deleteUser('my_user_id');
      await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

      expect(wrapper.vm.$st.toast.open).toBeCalledWith({
        type: 'error',
        content: 'There was an error trying to delete this font. Please try again.',
      });
    });
```

**deleteUser method**

```js
    async deleteUser(userId) {
        this.setLoading(true);
        fontService
          .deleteUser(userId)
          .then(() => {
            this.$toast.open({
              type: 'success',
              content: 'User was successfully deleted',
            });
            this.getFonts();
          })
          .catch(() => {
            this.$st.toast.open({
              type: 'error',
              content: 'There was an error trying to delete this font. Please try again.',
            });
          })
          .finally(() => {
            this.setLoading(false);
          });
      }
```

**jest log**

```bash
    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: {"content": "There was an error trying to delete this font. Please try again.", "type": "error"}

    Number of calls: 0
```

Comment: You set your mock function on `wrapper.vm.$toast.open` but then you use `this.$st.toast.open` in your component, so I understand those are two different functions.

Comment: deleteUser doesn't return a promise, this makes it impossible to chain and hard to test. Mocked fontService.deleteUser doesn't return a promise